# How many planes contain 2 specific parallel lines in vector space $ℝ^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Taking 2 parallel lines in $ℝ^3$, how many planes contain those 2 specific parallel lines? I'm certain it is either one unique plane or infinitely many planes but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

By definition,  parallel lines in three dimensional space are coplanar (Share a plane).  Lines that don't intersect but don't share a plane are called "skew".
There's a unique plane for any 3 non-collinear points, and so you can take 2 points from 1 line and 1 point from the other to find the unique plane.  You can find the equation of that plane by forming 2 vectors out of the three points thus found and taking their vector cross product.   This gets you the normal vector to the plane.

Answer (score 1):

If the lines are distinct, then there's exactly one plane. If the two lines are identical, then there are infinitely many planes containing them (or it).